# Google Drive API for javascript cannot get thumbnail link

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm using `files.list()` to get files from google drive and none of the files have thumbnailLinks. I'd like to avoid using `files.get()` if possible.

I've tried using `files.get()` instead, and messed around with the scopes quite a bit. None of it works. I've used very similar code before in the API for java, and it works just fine there.

```
var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata';

// ... 

gapi.client.drive.files.list({
    'pageSize': 50,
    'fields': "*",
    'q': "'" + current_folder + "' in parents",
    'pageToken': current_page
}).then(function(response) {
    // do stuff
});
```

It should return all fields for each file, including thumbnailLink. The rest of the fields are present, including hasThumbnail and thumbnailVersion

Comment: Can I ask you about the mimeType of files that you want to retrieve the thumbnailLink?

Comment: All files, mostly images.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I had asked about the mimeType of the files. Can I ask you about the kinds of image files?

Comment: `image/jpeg`, mostly

Comment: Thank you for replying. Files with JPEG format can be retrieve the thumbnail image. When you see the files on Google Drive at your browser, can you see the thumbnail? I think that when you can see them, the thumbnail can be retrieved.

Comment: Yes, I can see the thumbnails in the browser

Comment: In my environment, when the thumbnail can be seen at browser, the thumbnail link can be retrieved. So I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 0):

When having confusing results like this I find it best to use the interactive feature of the Google Drive API documentation:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list

Performing a list operation with a wildcard ('*') fields specifier results in a ton of information being returned including the thumbnail link, here's a sample of the results:

> "version": "2",    "webContentLink":
>   "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1L5rs4MwXoDeF7jo9EuVHFr3lgevTnElX&export=download",
>   "webViewLink":
>   "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L5rs4MwXoDeF7jo9EuVHFr3lgevTnElX/view?usp=drivesdk",
>   "iconLink":
>   "https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/16/type/application/pdf",
>   "hasThumbnail": true,    "thumbnailLink":
>   "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/aH5WzHIjCBBb3gjFXkf5bVD_lsJR0PsPuC-1gtW86MrVYVs8NUuMY_lmlcruAsv2L_A15ITAcgA=s220",
>   "thumbnailVersion": "1",    "viewedByMe": true,    "viewedByMeTime":
>   "2020-04-06T18:27:08.996Z",    "createdTime":
>   "2020-04-06T18:27:08.996Z",    "modifiedTime":
>   "2020-04-06T18:27:08.996Z",    "modifiedByMeTime":
>   "2020-04-06T18:27:08.996Z",    "modifiedByMe": true,

So I'd suggest debugging your query with that and seeing if you get the same result.